# Did an American soldier stop riots in Iraq by banning food trucks?

Tags: iraq

I remember hearing a story once that went something like this:

A behavior specialist for the US Army was sent to a city in Iraq where civil unrest frequently broke out. While studying a major plaza in the city, he noticed a few things:

First, a crowd would gather.
Next, the food trucks would arrive to serve the crowd.
Then, a riot would break out.

So, he decided to try prohibiting the food trucks from entering the plaza. His plan worked - the next day's crowd would gather and simply disperse.

I was unable to verify this story, however.

Comment: There's a bit of a difference between preventing food trucks stopping in one particular location and "banning food trucks".

Comment: Yes, when crowds get denied their access to food they usually just disperse pacifically. It is not as if the lack of food had ever started riots or revolutions. Maybe they just did send the trucks to different locations to allow too many people gathering together?

Comment: is a "food truck" in this anecdote something that sells sandwiches and coffee in the town square, or a large aid truck dispensing bags of millet to starving aid recipients? Big difference.

Comment: @Kate: The trucks may have been selling the food.

Comment: @KillingTime: The trucks were prohibited from entering the square.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, here is the source of that story (link at bottom):

> “I had been in Iraq for about two months when I heard about an ofﬁcer conducting an impromptu habit modiﬁcation program in Kufa, a small city ninety miles south of the capital. He was an army major who had analyzed videotapes of recent riots and had identiﬁed a pattern: Violence was usually preceded by a crowd of Iraqis gathering in a plaza or other open space and, over the course of several hours, growing in size. Food vendors would show up, as well as spectators. Then, someone would throw a rock or a bottle and all hell would break loose.

> When the major met with Kufa’s mayor, he made an odd request: Could they keep food vendors out of the plazas? Sure, the mayor said. A few weeks later, a small crowd gathered near the Masjid al-Kufa, or Great Mosque of Kufa. Throughout the afternoon, it grew in size. Some people started chanting angry slogans. Iraqi police, sensing trouble, radioed the base and asked U.S. troops to stand by. At dusk, the crowd started getting restless and hungry. People looked for the kebab sellers normally ﬁlling the plaza, but there were none to be found. The spectators left. The chanters became dispirited. By 8 p.m., everyone was gone.

> When I visited the base near Kufa, I talked to the major. You wouldn’t necessarily think about a crowd’s dynamics in terms of habits, he told me. But he had spent his entire career getting drilled in the psychology of habit formation.” *[Fastcompany.com](https://www.fastcompany.com/3024892/understanding-how-habits-rule-our-lives)*